# JBoss EAP 7.3 keystore password encryption in standalone.xml

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

In my application passwords are stored in custom `*.properties` files, and they can be encrypted by application and saved back encrypted, so at the next app startup they will be encrypted and JBoss can not decrypt them by itself. I need to decrypt them, cause there are SSL truststore and keystore passwords between them and I reference them in `standalone.xml` as `${app.password}` and SSL context fails to start if passwords are encrypted. Is there any way to decrypt them before server SSL context is initialized?